# create table with fixed header of with split word in c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, multidimensional-array, datagridview

i want to create table in windows form c#. i get the word, split it and i want to set its char array as header of table.when i add new word, i want to split it, set it in new row under header, and compare each character with same colume of header.i don't know number of words that enter in form and the count of words character, how can i create it?
example:

```
word for header: book --> split it and set in header
new word :       bird --> split it and set in new row 

table:
b o o k
b i r d
```

another question:
if my windows form is closed and opened again, i want to give these words again, and i dont want to lose theme.
thanks for helping...

update:

```
  private void wordbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    char[] list = wordBox.Text.Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray();
    var repeatedChars = wordBox.Text.Replace(" ", "").ToCharArray().GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(y => y.Count() > 1).Select(g => new { Letter = g.First(), Count = g.Count() });
    int repeatCount = repeatedChars.Count();
    int listCount = list.Count();
    int cell = repeatCount + listCount + 2;

    List<char[]> ll = new List<char[]>();
    ll.Add(list);

   // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //i want to create table for words by characters
    }
```

but when i send new word, list just has it, another words are cleared.

Comment: i want to create game same puzzle, one word is secret, and other send words to find it

Comment: Please add your current code to the question. Let us know where you encounter the problem.

Comment: What happens if the second word is longer than the first one?

Comment: Second word must be equal to first one. i want to show error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a class variable:

```
DataTable dt;
```

In your `wordbtn_Click method`, you may add the following code after the existing one:

```
if (dt == null)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        var dc = dt.Columns.Add(String.Format("column_{0}", i));
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = list[i].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = Padding.Empty;
    }
}
else
{
    if (list.Length != dt.Columns.Count)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Word length does not match.");
        return;
    }
    var dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        dr[i] = list[i];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Alex Filipovici :)